# Detect thread end

Tags: c++11, stdthread, stdasync

I would like to detect thread end in c++11 but I don't know how to do, it's look like that "get" block program, here is what I've done:

```
void Object::init()
{
    this->thread = std::async( std::launch::async, &State::load, stateInstance );
}

/* A method in a loop */
void Object::run()
{
    bool ready = this->thread.get();
    if( ready )
    {
      /* do something */
    }
    else
    {
       /* draw interface, manage event, … */
    }
}
```

My program don't go in the "else" in "run" method, program is stuck on "this->thread->get()" while state isn't load.

How can I handle that?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, have you verified that `State::load()` will actually finish?

Comment: Yes, State::load end ~3 seconds later, but "get" method block execution. (In the "else", I would like to animate a loader)

Comment: I love how you named the `future` 'thread'. You know, just for added confusion :/

Comment: What's the type of `stateInstance`? 'Cause, if it's an object or a reference, you need `std::ref()` with that!

Comment: @sehe: Haha, it's just for testing :).
stateInstance is a State pointer ("State* stateInstance" as parameter), I've tried with and without `std::ref`, my state object method is loaded successfully. It's just that I can detect method's end from `run` method (`State::load`, load HD textures and files, so it take time).

Comment: @LongDuZboub: To be honest I can't see the immediate problem then. Have you tried running a small sample program that uses `std::async` first (like [this one](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async)), just to see if your C++11 compiler's implementation of `std::async` isn't buggy?

Comment: Another thing to look for is to see if you've called `this->thread.get()` prior to the `Object::run()` call. You can't call `std::future::get()` twice, because [it makes the `std::future` invalid and calling `get()` on an invalid `std::future` is undefined](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/get).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure what the trouble is, but here's an idea using `wait_for` ([compiled on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4e2da85223fc737d)):

```
#include <future>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

struct State
{
    void load() { 
        std::cout << "working\n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(4));
        std::cout << "done\n";
    }
};

struct Object
{
    /* A method in a loop */
    bool run()
    {
        switch(future.wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100)))
        {
            case std::future_status::ready:
                {
                    /* do something */
                }
                return false;
            case std::future_status::timeout:
                {
                    /* draw interface, manage event, … */
                }
            case std::future_status::deferred:
            default:
                return true;
        }
    }

    Object()  { init(); }
    ~Object() { if (future.valid()) future.wait(); }
  private:
    void init()
    {
        future = std::async(std::launch::async, &State::load, &stateInstance);
    }

    State stateInstance;
    std::future<void> future;
};

int main()
{
    Object test;

    while (test.run());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
while(!this->thread.valid())
{ //do smthg
}else{
}
```

Your get locks, because get wants to retrieve the result of the future this->thread. therefor it does wait for this result to be ready, and returns it.

valid just tell if this future result is ready

Comment: This is going to cause the 100% CPU usage while also doing nothing while waiting on the thread.

Comment: yes, in do something you "do something" so for instance a sleep. I don't know what is planned in this do something code

Comment: That's still a very "hacky" way of doing things. Even if you used `Sleep()` or something, now there's latency in how soon the thread can resume, and the thread would have to wake up every once in a while just to see if it can resume. Why not just let the operating system notify the waiting thread?

Comment: This is currently an issue of discussion in the proposals for the next sstandard. they want to add function to chain actions and add the keyword await to do std::async(function1()).then(function2()). See proposals from sutter on isocpp.org

Comment: Thank, but it didn't work :/. `this->thread.valid()` never return true. (But with a std::cout from `State::load` I can see that my method have reached his end (State::load return true).